# I have a list of names, and tags per row (each tag is in a new column), how do I get a pivot of names per tag

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, google-spreadsheets

My data is set up in such a way where I have

```
John  alpha    beta   gamma  
Mary  beta     gamma  upsilon  
Zack  upsilon  alpha  omega
```

What i get is only the first column of data...

```
name  Alpha  Beta  Upsilon
John  1      
Mary         1
Zack               1
```

I'd like to get a pivot table with something like

```
Name  Alpha  Beta  Gamma  Upsilon  Omega
John  1      1     1
Mary         1     1      1
Zack  1                   1        1
```

How do I do it?

Comment: I'm confused, you answered your own question, make a pivot table. What is your question?

Comment: My apologies this may be a really easy fix and I may be using the wrong terminology. Each piece of information is in a separate cell, and when I pivot, I only get the values in the first column, not the subsequent columns. I'll update my example.

Comment: Oh, my mistake as well, pivot table don't really work that way. Is there ever duplicates?

Comment: There are no duplicates per single row, however a new row may have the first column different, and then similar values in subsequent columns. This sheet was generated from a list of names with tags appearing afterwards, comma delimited.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this depends on how you have things set up.  For example, if you have your results table on the same rows as your original data, but with the "properties" listed as the column header, you could use a simple `COUNTIF`.

In the screenshot example:

```
J2:  =IF(COUNTIF(Sheet4!$A2:$E2,J$1)=0,"",COUNTIF(Sheet4!$A2:$E2,J$1))
```

and fill right and down

[image]

If your requirements are more complex, you will need to be more specific.

**Edit:** In a comment you indicated that the tags would not repeat in any given row.  That being the case, the formula can be simplified:

```
J2:  =IF(COUNTIF(Sheet4!$A2:$E2,J$1)=0,"",1)
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @FyzxNerd  Since you posted a comment indicating that the tags/properties would not repeat in any given row, the formula can be simplified.  See my **Edit** in my response.